# MS Access - show field combinations using SQL TRANSFORM or similar

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba

I have a table with a list of accommodation types and the people using them. Some people use more than one accommodation type. How can I show a count of the number of people using each accommodation type and the number in each combination of possible accommodation types? The users in each category are already unique within that category.

Eg:

```
AccomType NameID
A         1
A         2
B         1
B         3
B         4
B         5
C         1
C         4
```

I'd like output similar to

```
AccomType Count
A         2
B         4
C         2
A&B       1
B&C       2
A&C       2
A&B&C     3
```

I don't think TRANSFORM can do this, is it posible to do this in SQL? I'd prefer to not use VBA, though can if it's the only/easiest way. Also, there is a field in the same table for year (08/09, 09/10 etc.), to filter by that I plan to use WHERE, unless that influences anyones suggested solution?

EDIT: I tried a pivottable, but that won't let me use the same field for both row and field and also won't show where the three intersection combination (A&B&C occurs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to do a query for each group you want do a do a UNION. And then count the results

```
SELECT 
    AccomType,
    SUM([Tick]) as Count

FROM (

    SELECT
        "A" as AccomType,  1 as Tick,  1 as SortOrder
    FROM
        Name_AccomType
    WHERE
        AccomType = "A"

    UNION ALL SELECT
           "B" as AccomType,  1 as Tick,  2 as SortOrder
    FROM
        Name_AccomType
    WHERE
        AccomType = "B"

    UNION ALL SELECT
        "C" as AccomType, 1 as Tick, 3 as SortOrder
    FROM
        Name_AccomType
    WHERE
        AccomType = "C"

    UNION ALL  SELECT 
        "A&B" as AccomType, 1 as Tick, 4 as SortOrder
    FROM 
        Name_AccomType
    WHERE
        AccomType  in ("A", "B")
    GROUP BY NameID
    HAVING COUNT(NameID) = 2

    UNION ALL  SELECT 
        "B&C" as AccomType, 1 as Tick, 5 as SortOrder
    FROM 
        Name_AccomType
    WHERE   
        AccomType  in ("B", "C")
    GROUP BY NameID
    HAVING COUNT(NameID) = 2

    UNION ALL  SELECT 
            "A&C" as AccomType, 1 as Tick, 6 as SortOrder
    FROM 
       Name_AccomType
    WHERE
       AccomType  in ("A", "C")
    GROUP BY NameID
    HAVING COUNT(NameID) = 2

    UNION ALL  SELECT 
            "A&B&C" as AccomType, 1 as Tick, 7 as SortOrder
    FROM 
       Name_AccomType
    WHERE
       AccomType  in ("A", "B", "C")
    GROUP BY NameID
    HAVING COUNT(NameID) = 3
) as t
GROUP BY 
    AccomType, 
    SortOrder
ORDER BY 
    SortOrder
```

Comment: Actually, can I ask why you used "A&B" as AccomType, 1 as **Count**, 4 as SortOrder when you used **tick** everywhere else?

Comment: @Vbevan that was an error I'll fix it when I get in front if a machine, but its a style error. Only the column names in the first select in the union counts.